# Programmatically add sites to IIS

Tags: iis

I would like to add a new site to IIS with code or script rather than using the UI.

Does IIS have any kind of API that I can use to do this?

Ideally it is something I can invoke from C# in a browser, but if I have to code it in powershell and then use C# to invoke the powershell I would be happy to do that too.

The use case is that I am building a plugin based site that will have dozens of sub-sites.  I want the main site to be able to manage that sub-sites using a browser.

It will do things like shutdown, point to new URL, start, and add new site.

Comment: You can get some ideas from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet), an example for you:

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
Site mySite = serverManager.Sites.Add("Racing Cars Site", "d:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\racing",  8080);
mySite.ServerAutoStart = true;
serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

More information about how to use Microsoft.Web.Administration you can refer to this link:

[How to Use Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration).